# Execution failed for task ':expo-constants:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: react-native, gradle, build, expo

Execution failed for task ':expo-constants:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

These two errors also come
Unresolved reference: deviceYearClass
'getDeviceYearClass' overrides nothing

Comment: To achieve your specific requirement, it would be helpful to provide more context and detail about your project. By providing a more comprehensive description of your situation, you'll receive more accurate and detailed answers that are better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do 1 or 2 things:

1. Upgrade `expo-constants` to the version where they finally remove `deviceYearClass` from the source code. I did some investigation, and it looks like it should be version 14.4.2 at least: https://github.com/expo/expo/commit/e6258d39ac388e80bf1b1c7249d5888c9acc8e1e#diff-eae51642ed7ddb2da4dc805c0a022b8c86a1f720b3d585e636415f64cbac9bcbR13
2. (optional) You might or might not need to add `expo-device` as a separate package.